# Laravel - route model binding with request headers

Tags: laravel

I am wondering is it possible to do something similar to route model binding, but with request headers. I have a query that I check on my api endpoints, that looks like this:

```
User::where('telephone', $request->header('x-user'))->firstOrFail();
```

Is it possible to somehow avoid repeating this query in every method in controllers, but to apply it to routes, so that I could just get the user object just like in a route model binding with type hinting in a function, for every route that in an api routes folder:

```
public function userTransactions(User $user)
{
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a middleware and assign it to the desired routes.

Option 1

In your middleware do:

```
$user = User::where('telephone', $request->header('x-user'))->firstOrFail();

request()->merge(['user_model' => $user]);
```

You can then `request()->get('user_model')` anywhere in your controller

Option 2

Start by creating a global scope class that conforms to your query. Here you'd get the header value and use that in the scope.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#global-scopes

Next in the middleware, add the scope to the model using `addGlobalScope`

```
User::addGlobalScope(new HeaderScope())
```

Now all queries for User will have a where clause with your header value.

You can subsequently remove the scope or ignore global scopes if needed.

Comment: But, how can I pass this user object then to a controller from the middleware?

Comment: Edited my answer with more info.

Comment: I still don't see how would I pass this variable to a controller? You just showed me how to do a global scope, but what I am intrested is how to do a query in middleware, so that I can pass the value of it as parameter to a function in a controller for example?

Comment: Ok in that case just run the query directl y in the middleware and then `request()->merge(['user_model' => $user])`

Comment: See my edited answer. No need to pass it as a parameter this way.